# VS2010 Database Unit Testing Inheriting from ResultSetCondition

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, vs-unit-testing-framework

I'm using the VS2010 database unit testing framework. I've already created a condition inheriting from DataSetTestCondition and that worked fine. I'm now trying to write a condition inheriting from ResultSetCondition, but I keep getting the error:

**'DBUnitTestConditions.ConditionMulti' does not implement inherited abstract member 'Microsoft.Data.Schema.UnitTesting.Conditions.ResultSetCondition.DoAssert(System.Data.DataTable)'**

This is basically the code I'm using:

```
using Microsoft.Data.Schema.UnitTesting.Conditions;
using System.Data;

namespace DBUnitTestConditions
{
    public class ConditionMulti : ResultSetCondition  
    {
        public ConditionMulti()
        {

        }

        public void DoAssert(DataTable dt)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

If I try to use the object browser to have a look in ResultSetCondition there is nothing refering to DosAssert there. But if I use the Solution Navigator I see DoAssert, but it appears to be private. Any help would be appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Complete rewrite

I've checked the source code:

```
namespace Microsoft.Data.Schema.UnitTesting.Conditions
{
     public abstract class ResultSetCondition : TestCondition
     {
          //...      
          internal abstract void DoAssert(DataTable resultSet);
     }
}
```

So the `DoAssert` marked as `internal`. So you cannot inherit from `ResultSetCondition` because
`internal abstract` means that the class can only be inherited in the assembly that defined it.
There is no way around that.

Comment: I tried that also and that gives the additional error: **'DBUnitTestConditions.ConditionMulti.DoAssert(System.Data.DataTable)': no suitable method found to override**

Comment: Seems a bit strange for MS to do this given that the class itself is public. I'll have a look at writting something based on TestConsition. Thanks!